# How to select a text box and resize using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to resize the text box size using VBA. To do that I change the rectangle number in the VBA every time which is not serving the purpose of VBA.

I need to resize the selected text box based on value in other cells.

```
Sub ResizeTextBox()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 39")
    shp.Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(Range("Y5").Value)
    shp.Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(Range("Y6").Value)
End Sub
```

How do I resize the selected text box based on value in cell `Y5` and `Y6`?

Comment: You say that you want to increase the size of a "text box", yet, your code shows that you are resizing a shape. Which is it?

Comment: `Set shp = Selection`

Comment: @Ahmad, I don't want to increase the text box size rather I want to resize, So the size would be increased or decreased.

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks for your reply. I am not a pro coder but try my best to develop with some myself. But here I got stuck. Could you please help me to write the line?

Comment: Replace your existing line with my line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub ResizeTextBox()
    Dim shp As Shape

    'check a range is not selected
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        With Selection
            .Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(Range("Y5").Value)
            .Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(Range("Y6").Value)
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "First select a a shape for resizing"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank Tim. It means a lot to me. It is working perfect.